# IDE для ActionScript 3 под Linux/Mac ?

Tags: ide, mac, linux, actionscript

IDE для ActionScript 3 под Linux/Mac ?

Comment: Искал в свое время ченить нормальное, все-равно лучше чем flashbuilder нет ничего, достойного под nix вообще ничего не попадалось, да оно и не странно, adobe вообще никак linux не поддерживает... Лично я решил эту проблему покупкой еще одного компа б/у :)<br>
Терь у меня и Windows и Linux, правда у меня их три, на третем mac..<br> В любом случае когда я занимался этим вопросом реально было пренципиально найти хоть чтото стоящее, но как можно было понять из мною вышенаписаного - ничего из этого не вышло :(

Comment: > adobe вообще никак linux не поддерживает
До недавнего времени air был и для nix, flash player для nix тоже есть так что.
Flashbuiler'а очень не хватает под никсы, но IDEA даже круче, минус только что она платная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

World famouse [intellij idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/flex_ide.html), жаль что только платная версия. Работает еще и на винде. Есть на 30 дней тирал.

Из свободного есть [as3ide](http://as3ide.sourceforge.net/) - надстройка над eclipse. Но последняя версия вышла в прошлом году, до сих пор пре альфа версия. Крайне не стабильна.

Comment: в есть что freeware ?

Comment: дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали [Realaxy ActionScript Editor](http://www.realaxy.com/aboutEditor/index)?

Comment: не очень как то и платная

Comment: сейчас ее открыл, очень похожа на обрезанную IDEA. RASE базируется на ней?

Comment: @rnd_d Честно говоря не знаю, но скорее всего нет.

Comment: based on JetBrains MPS, вот почему так похожа на IDEA.

Comment: @VioLet, а как вам ее нетекстовый редактор кода?

Comment: @Angry Bird я на AS3 писал всего пару раз, но мне эта система довольно понравилась (как человеку, который слабо разбирается в синтаксисе).